# insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' same error using python mysql

Tags: python, tkinter

i am a beginner of python.Search data how to pass into the relavent textboxs using python mysql. what tried so far i atttached code below.search data display successfully i saw the data on the console.how to pass into the relavent textboxs i don't know
Error **insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' same error**

```
  from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector

def Ok():
    global myresult
    studname = e1.get()
    coursename = e2.get()

    mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="smschool")
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()

    try:

        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM record where id = ?",(studname,))


        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

        for x in myresult:
            print(x)
           e2.insert(str(x[2]))
           e3.insert(str(x[3]))


    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       mysqldb.rollback()
       mysqldb.close()

root = Tk()
root.title("Search Mysql")
root.geometry("300x200")

Label(root, text="Student ID").place(x=10, y=10)
Button(root, text="Search", command=Ok ,height = 1, width = 13).place(x=140, y=40)
Label(root, text="Course").place(x=10, y=80)
Label(root, text="Fee").place(x=10, y=120)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=140, y=10)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.place(x=140, y=80)

e3 = Entry(root)
e3.place(x=140, y=120)

root.mainloop()
```

**Full Error**

**Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement**

Comment: mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM record where id = %s", studname) i got the error of this line 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: may i ask why you are using mysql for a mariadb server?

Comment: try changing `%s` to `?`, take a look [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/)

Comment: Not the answer but try making this `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM record where id = '" + studname + "'")` to `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM record where id = ?",(studname,))` and why not use `e1.insert(myresult)` to isnert into Entry, which entry do you want to insert onto?Make sure to say `global myresult` on top of your OK()

Comment: i edited code above please check above what is the problem now i got the error Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: Please edit the Q with the full error code

Comment: search record must be pass into courename and fee textboxes

Comment: i edited the error above sir

Comment: im not sure as to why the error has popped up, but then the problem might be becuase it says that your using a mariadb database and parameter markers vary, so i think you should take a look at how your database was made, to begin with

Comment: sir at the console data displyed successfullly (1, 'kobinath', 'Java', 12000)
thing is i cannot pass the relavent textboxes

Comment: e2.insert(x('fee'))

Comment: try `e2.insert(x[3])`

Comment: got this error insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'  same error

Comment: try `e2.insert(0,x[3])` or `e2.insert(END,x[3])`

Comment: now working sir but when i enter the first student id 1  display course fee 12000 success second time enter student id 2 display course fee 15000 on the textbox without removing prevoius text 120001500014000 like wise

Comment: you have to use `e2.delete(0,END)` to delete whats inside it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert into the the `Entry` widget, you can use something like `insert()` method. But since your fetching of data from the database is inside of a function and you are trying to access it outside the function you have to make it available to the `global` scope.

```
def Ok():
    global myresult
    studname = e1.get()
    coursename = e2.get()
........
```

Now you can access your `myresult` from outside `Ok()` too. So now you can insert it to the corresponding entrybox by saying

```
e1.insert(0,myresult) #can be e2.insert(0,myresult) or e3.insert(0,myresult) depending on where you want to insert
```

You can remove this from your code, as it is in the main block and is available to use almost everywhere

```
global e1
global e2
global e3
```

Also, on top of all this I recommend you use paramtetric substiturion instead of concatenating the `execute` statements as it is a more secure way.

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM record where id = ?",(studname,)) #would be %s for mysql version
```

Here, `?` is a placeholder because you are using `mariadb`(as the error in the comments suggests) and I recommend you change your `mysql.connector` to `mariadb` (as your using a mariadb server and not a mysql server, so some syntaxes do vary), easily just say

```
pip install mariadb
```

and

```
import mariadb
```

and you can follow the [documentation here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/)

If any doubts or errors, do let me know.

Cheers

Comment: sir have doubt if i change as mariadb can i fetch the data from mysql database

Comment: The errors says that you are using mariadb database, if not you can continue using mysql connector but check out which placeholder works

Comment: mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="smschool") i got the error of this line sir

Comment: on top of try saying `import mysql.connector as mysql` and use `mysq.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="smschool")` and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
root = Tk()
msg='hello world!'
w=Text(master=root, exportselection=0, width=20, height=3)
w.pack()
w.insert(END, msg)
```

Comment: I hope this is what you ask for